# Must switch views for "[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];" to work

Tags: ios, uiappearance, bartintcolor

I'm setting the bar tint color to be different on button click but you have to switch views for the following method to take effect. I have no clue why it is not.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

> **The reason for the error：**
>
> `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor
>   randomColor]];` doesn't work because the UIViewController has been
>   initialized!!!

**The solution ：**

(1) The UIAppearance user to set global effect in AppDelegate didFinishLaunch Function.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];
    return YES;
}
```

(2) About initialized UIViewController ,you should user self.navigationController.navigationBar to set color can have an effect on the app life cycle as well.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor randomColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationBar *navBar=self.navigationController.navigationBar;
[navBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Try this

this is how i tested it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar=self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    [navBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
}
```

Since i dont have any button on screen i just changed one of my table delegate function.

Comment: I'm calling this in my AppDelegate so that doesn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: i just test these two line on one of my projects its working perfectly. If you want i can post screen shots. though i am using these to line locally not delegate. just a function with two lines in it. let me know

Comment: hmm, how exactly are you calling them universally if you call them that way?

Comment: How did you put that in the app delegate?

Comment: don't put it in app delegate put in viewcontroller where you button is clicked or in function that is connected to your button where action is being performed

Comment: I need it in the app delegate because of the thing I am trying to accomplish (dark mode)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49873/discussion-between-m-farhan-and-colton-anglin)